# Export telegram and whatsapp contacts to vcf?

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger, telegram

I have lost most of my contacts on the phone account, but they still exist in my telegram account. How can i move them to phone or export them?

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to transfer contacts from telegram account to your android smart phone:
Just install a contact backup software from google store like "+contact backup" and after that make a back up from your contacts; it automatically collect all of your contacts from every account that you have on your phone: telegram,google,phone etc.
after completing your back up you can import the created file to your phone or google account.
it's finished

Comment: Can you please suggest any such app, with its link? I don't seem to able to find any such app with the particular functionality of backing up for each Account as you say..

Answer (score 1):

For WhatsApp, here's a trick that might work, but you need to use *WhatsApp Web* to do that:

1. **[Download your WhatsApp Contacts with the help of the bookmarklet here](http://www.labnol.org/internet/whatsapp-contacts/28789/)**.
   (The contacts get exported as a CSV list)
2. Now you can convert the CSV file to .vcf using some tools available..
   Here's a tool that you can try: **[CSV to vCard](http://www.csvtovcard.com)**

Comment: Unfortunately, [I don't find any such tricks for Telegram](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/146157/how-do-i-export-telegram-contacts-to-my-phone).