# How do I export Telegram contacts to my phone?

Tags: contacts, backup, factory-reset, data-recovery, telegram

I'm new here.

My little brother **accidentally** touched the **"reset factory"**  button in settings, and now I don't have my contacts on my phone! I have 1500 (**almost 400 business**) contacts with more than 670 profile pictures!

I rooted my phone and used recovery tools in W7, but nothing worked for me! I just recovered 10 old contacts, so God bless the Telegram app because I saw my contacts there,  but there are no contacts in my phone app. Is there any way to import contacts from the Telegram app to my phone app?

If possible please tell me how to fix this issue. Any guidance also in programming issues like linux terminals will be accepted in my way.

(Note: I used search in this site but there was nothing for my issue,
just found a [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/132876/export-telegram-and-whatsapp-contacts-to-vcf/137100#137100) that a buddy wrote there:

> "Just install a contact backup software from google store like "+contact backup" and after that make a back up from your contacts."

But there's no app in the app store with that name!

Comment: Was your phone encrypted?

Comment: @MatthewRead no! I rooted that but only 100 contacts recovered and about 1000 of them just have names on them! Without numbers!

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/132876/export-telegram-and-whatsapp-contacts-to-vcf

Answer (score 1):

Just go to your accounts menu and select telegram\ accounts and then tap the current account and turn on Sync contacts. This way you can have all your contacts whom they have an telegram account.

Comment: By 'Export', he means exporting the contacts to his storage offline, not syncing online..

Answer (score 1):

Use 'ExportTelegramContacts' software on github.
https://github.com/salarcode/ExportTelegramContacts

Read the readme file and follow the instruction. when it comes to "export contacts without phone numbers" press "No".