# Restrict contacts from knowing I am on WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Am I right in understanding that when one installs whatsapp everyone in the contacts on my phone knows I am on whatsapp (at least the ones who have whatsapp)

I do not want the above to happen. So if I put in another SIM card, then can I avoid the contacts on my primary SIM knowing I am on whatsapp and restrict to only the contacts on the new/secondary SIM. Or will WhatApp anyway broadcast to all contacts on all SIMs?

My basic aim is to expose the fact that I have whatsapp to a limited set of people - hence the second SIM.

Kindly let me know

Ananth

Comment: Hello. Follow this: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/201826/96277

Comment: @Firelord This is more from a standpoint of one SIM of contacts and WhatsApp with that number and to limit the contacts visible. I think DUAL SIM is equivalent to what you said if you set up the second SIM with only contacts you want on WhatsApp. So your primary SIM and all its contacts dont know you use WhatsApp - at least this is my understanding from the answer below from NatWeb Solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer to your question is - everyone who has your new number will see that you are on WhatsApp. WhatsApp is tied to mobile number only and it will not "broadcast to any other sim". If you don't give this number to another person then they will not be able to  see or contact you.

Also a hint. If you have dual SIM phone you can use normal WhatsApp and business WhatsApp (it's free) on the same phone simultaneously (using 2 different numbers).

Comment: Cool. So if I put in another new SIM and use its number while installing/verifying WhatsApp only those people who get this new SIM's number will be able to see me on WhatsApp. All contacts on my current SIM will remain unaware of my WhatsApp usage - is my understanding correct? If so that is exactly what I want. I dont want to use whatsapp at all but my small business if forcing me to do so, hence I want this demarcation. We already have another number which is WhatsApp business so I do not need that. Please confirm my understanding before I go ahead with the plan :) Thanks for the help !

Comment: @ananth yes that is correct:) you can use new number and only people who will have that number will see you have WhatsApp on it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Will get my second SIM and get that number set up as my WhatsApp number. Appreciate the help :)