# Can a user create a "work profile" for an enterprise account?

Tags: profiles, android-enterprise

So I added a work related Google for enterprise account but it's now showing up along side my personal accounts. I know there is a way that the enterprise admin (which is not me) can force the account to be separated from my personal accounts (different gmail/calendar/drive apps, separate file spaces, restrictions on transferring data, etc.), but they seemed to have not elected to do that.

Is there any way **I** can cause that to happen without having to involve them?

---

Note: I've found the option for adding multiple users, but that's not what I'm looking for as that seems to be a only-one-is-logged-in-at-a-time thing where as the thing I've used before has only one session just with duplication and isolation of the apps.

Comment: You can isolate workplace from personal data by using [Shelter](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/201826/131553)

Comment: Work Profile Device Policy can only be changed by admin. It nullifies the purpose if modifications are possible otherwise.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Does it mean isolating by shelter won't work? I haven't used Shelter in such a situation but see no reason why it shouldn't work

Comment: @beeshyams it looks like OP has already a DPC app installed by some admin. So it depends on the existing policy if it allows installing another DPC app (Shelter) to create multiple profiles or not. This may happen possibly (I'm not sure though) but I haven't seen a practical case so far. Usually only one Work Profile app can be installed at a time.

Comment: Actually, the issue is that there is no Work Profile Device Policy at all. And I don't really care how it's configured as long as it is. -- Enabling it in the first place is the one things that a non-admin could do that *wouldn't* nullify the purpose. Maybe I'm just viewing it from the other side; I want to use a Device Policy to isolate the *non-work* stuff from the work stuff.